# React hooks value renders correctly but not updated inside a callback function of addEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm implementing infinite scroll with hooks in a functional component, I'm having an issue where I'm unable to access the updated value inside the scroll event callback function, here's my code:

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const initItems = ['First', 'Second','Third','Fourth','Fifth']

const Example = ({title}) => {
const [posts, setPosts] = useState({
        data: [],
        page: 1
    });

    console.log('FN RENDER')

    const handleScroll = (e) => {

        const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = e.target

      
        const bottom = scrollHeight - scrollTop === clientHeight;

        if (bottom) {
        
            console.log('page', posts.page) // page stays 1


            const nextPage = posts.page + 1

             setPosts(p => ({
                  data: [...p.data, 'Append'],
                  page: p.page + 1
              }))
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        console.log('USEEFFECT RENDER')

        setPosts(p => ({
            data: initItems,
            page: 1
        }))
        
        
//using ScrollBox for demo, originally I'm handling the scroll event on the document: document.addEventListener            
document.getElementById("ScrollBox").addEventListener('scroll',handleScroll);

        return () => document.getElementById("ScrollBox").removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }, []);


  return (
    <div> 
    <p>Page:{posts.page}</p>
    
    <div id="ScrollBox" class="scroll-box">
      {
         posts.data.map(k=> <p>{k} </p>)
      }
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
#ScrollBox{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
    overflow:auto;
    width:400px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

If you look into the console, the value of `page` stays `1` while it is rendered correctly. I used `useEffect` to attach the event. How can I get the right updated value inside `handleScroll`?

**-- Edit --**

How to get the updated value inside the callback of `addEventListener`? `#ScrollBox` is for the question demo, I instead need to detect scroll on `document`, which is the reason I'm using the event listener.

Answer (score 1):

The `useEffect` function only fires when the second parameter has changed. Since you have an empty second parameter, it will never update, and since it never updates, your event handler holds on to the stale closure from the first render no matter how many times you update the state.

You can fix your code by passing the the event listener directly inside the render function rather than in `useEffect`. You should not do direct DOM manipulation in react anyway.

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const initItems = ['First', 'Second','Third','Fourth','Fifth']

const Example = ({title}) => {
const [posts, setPosts] = useState({
        data: [],
        page: 1
    });

    console.log('FN RENDER')

    const handleScroll = (e) => {

        const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = e.target

      
        const bottom = scrollHeight - scrollTop === clientHeight;

        if (bottom) {
        
            console.log('page', posts.page) // page stays 1


            const nextPage = posts.page + 1

             setPosts(p => ({
                  data: [...p.data, 'Append'],
                  page: p.page + 1
              }))
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        console.log('USEEFFECT RENDER')
        // <!-- No event handler here -->
        setPosts(p => ({
            data: initItems,
            page: 1
        }))
        
        
    }, []);


  return (
    <div> 
    <p>Page:{posts.page}</p>
    
    <!-- NOTE THE EVENT HANDLER HERE -->
    <div id="ScrollBox" class="scroll-box"
         onScroll={handleScroll}
>
      {
         posts.data.map(k=> <p>{k} </p>)
      }
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
#ScrollBox{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
    overflow:auto;
    width:400px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Well, the thing is, that the element I want to select is `document` scroll instead of that div.. `#ScrollBox` is just to point out the issue.

Comment: You can add arguments to `useEffect` to force it to re-render if a specific argument has changed

Comment: That will re-initialize the state and also re-attach the event, I guess I will need to add conditions on when to initialize. But it will still re-attach the event on each update.

Comment: However, switched to a class component for now. works great. initialized the values in the constructor, and used componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount for attaching/detaching the event